# How to activate Xively device via Curl

Tags: curl, xively

Is it possible to activate a Xively device using cURL and if so could someone please post an example ?

The device is working well under the development account but I can't work out how to activate it.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be the following one based on [their documentation](https://xively.com/dev/docs/api/product_management/devices/activate_device/):

```
curl -k -L https://api.xively.com/v2/devices/ACTIVATION_CODE/activate -H "X-ApiKey: API_KEY_HERE"
```

Change `ACTIVATION_CODE` and `API_KEY_HERE` from the above url.

If you have problem with running the command, run it with adding `-v` option. And show us the verbose printout.

Comment: Here is some more info for you: https://gist.github.com/errordeveloper/4416171 (the script is not guaranteed to work on all systems, but it shows a bunch of useful pointer to how you could potentially use Ethernet MAC as serial)